# Global Test Variable in my JAX-WS Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I would like to know how to set a system property in my JAX-WS web service (on start up of the service) so that I can do a System.getProperty() in any class to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line option `-Dproperty=value` in the java process (for start the application server) for set a system property value. e.g.:

```
java -Dbrandon.f="some string" SomeClass
```

You can recover it with:

```
String value = System.getProperty("brandon.f");
```

---

#### Update

If you want to load a configuration file and use it in a JAX-WS, you can use a listener for load it in the application context if you wish. e.g.:

```
@WebListener
public class CacheListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Bean for store the configuration data.
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // Load file and read it.

        // Store the bean in application context.
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.setAttribute("myconfig", dummyCache);
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext context = sce.getServletContext();
        context.removeAttribute("myconfig");
    }

}
```

For get the configuration data in the service implementation:

```
@WebService
public class Test {

    @Resource
    private WebServiceContext svcCtx;

    @WebMethod(operationName = "testCode")
    public String testCode(@WebParam(name = "key") String key) {
        MessageContext msgCtx = svcCtx.getMessageContext();
        ServletContext ctx = (ServletContext) 
                msgCtx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_CONTEXT);
        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) 
                ctx.getAttribute("myconfig");
        return map.get("key");
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay, how about loading in a whole config file. Where would I do that?

Comment: You can use a listener.